# JTextField super.paintComponent() ignores background color when on Linux

Tags: java, linux, swing, jtextfield, paintcomponent

Alright, so I've been working on this for awhile and really at a loss. In my program, I am approaching a custom UI look and feel by creating new classes that extend certain `JComponent`s, overriding their `paintComponent` methods, and using those classes for the objects. This is where I'm lost, however. I have a simple window that asks the user to give it a directory, it then checks the directory, and changes the color of the text field (which is named `DraconicTextField`, extending `JTextField`) to red if it fails to create a directory at that location. I am developing this on two computers, using git to crossover. This *works* on Windows, but fails on Linux. Here is the code:

```java
class DraconicTextField extends JTextField {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int arcSize = 13;

    final Color textColor = new Color( 31, 31, 31 );
    final Color boxColor = new Color( 250, 250, 250 );
    final Color borderColor = new Color( 250, 250, 250, 0 );

    public DraconicTextField() {
        this.setOpaque( false ); //true gives the same result, but corners aren't rounded if set as such
        this.setForeground( textColor ); //Text color
        this.setBackground( boxColor );  //BG color
        this.putClientProperty( SwingUtilities2.AA_TEXT_PROPERTY_KEY, null );

        this.setFont( new Font( "Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18 ) );
        this.setFont( GUIUtils.getDefaultFont( this ).deriveFont( Font.PLAIN, 18f ) ); //GUIUtils is imported

        this.setBorder( new DraconicRoundBorder( arcSize, borderColor ) );

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent( Graphics graphics ) {
        Graphics2D graphics2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;

        graphics2d.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );
        graphics2d.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON );

        graphics2d.setColor( this.getBackground() );
        graphics2d.fillRoundRect( 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), arcSize, arcSize );

        super.paintComponent( graphics2d ); //I am almost certain this is the problem-causer

    }

}
```

To save some space, the main frame class simply calls `gamedirBox.setBackground(/*some color*/)` upon finding the directory to be invald. (Which I'm certain works!)

In my testing, I made a short (and terribly formatted) program to see if in fact I can change the color, and I can, but this does not override the `paintComponent` method. **Note that this code is *not* part of the above code!** Here is that code:

```java
class GuiBox extends JFrame {

    public JLabel thisIsTheLabel = this.label( "Hello again, world!" );
    public JTextField testBox = new JTextField();
    public JButton testButton = new JButton( "Change the color!" );

    private Random randy = new Random();

    public GuiBox( String title ) {
        super( title );

        this.setSize( 300, 400 );
        this.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

        testBox.setMinimumSize( new Dimension( 200, 40 ) );
        testBox.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 40 ) );
        testBox.setText( "This is some really long string so that flow layout stops being a ****." );

        testBox.setBackground( new Color( 240, 240, 240 ) );

        testButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                testBox.setBackground( new Color( randy.nextInt(255), randy.nextInt(255), randy.nextInt(255) ) );
                testBox.repaint(); //Notice, I do not override paintComponent()

            }


        });

        this.add( testBox );
        this.add( testButton );

        this.setVisible( true );

    }

    public static void createBox() {
        GuiBox window = new GuiBox( "test box" );

    }

}
```

Thank you tons for the help, guys!

**Edit -- Screenshots:**

Windows:
[image: Windows Functionality]

Linux:
[image: Linux Functionality]

Comment: super.paintComponent() will clear the background. So all your custom painting done before that statement will be lost.

Comment: @camickr Is this specific to swing on Linux? Like I mentioned, it works on windows, so that would lead me to imagine that super.paintComponent() uses getBackground() for the color in that case, but something else here. Additionally, the box is still a rounded rectangle, so I wouldn't imagine it is completely clearing it. Also, I forgot to mention, this is SE 8 if that makes any difference as well. Thank you, however!

Comment: ignore my first comment it is wrong.

Comment: I also see this problem on Linux. Any solution @Drayux?

Answer (score 1):

```
public JTextField testBox = new JTextField();
```

The code you posted isn't even using your custom text field.

if you do use your custom text field it still won't work, even on Windows.

```
this.setOpaque( false );
```

The above statement says that the component does NOT paint its own background. Therefore you will only see the background of the parent component.

Maybe the code appears to work because of your custom Border, but the text component itself will not be painting the background.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still doesn't work. As I mentioned in the post (sorry if it wasn't clear enough) the second block of code was a *separate* program that *does* work, so I can conclude that the problem is somewhere in my custom text field. I'll add some screenshots here really soon, but there is still coloration on Windows with setOpaque(false). I could be wrong, but I was aware that setting it to not paint it's own background in the superclass paint component is exactly what I want, so I can paint my own, as I do.

Answer (score 0):

The Nimbus LAF doesn't support setting a JTextField background color:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8058704